# Why is $\vec{v_1}^T \vec{v_2} = \vec{v_1} \cdot \vec{v_2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a symmetric matrix, and $\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}$ are eigenvectors of $A$ with distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, then

$$\vec{v_1}^T A \vec{v_2} = \vec{v_1}^T (\lambda_2 \vec{v_2}) = \lambda_2 (\vec{v_1}^T \vec{v_2}) = \lambda_2 (\vec{v_1} \cdot \vec{v_2}).$$

I don't understand why $\vec{v_1}^T \vec{v_2} = \vec{v_1} \cdot \vec{v_2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec{v_1} = \begin{bmatrix}\ a_1\\ \vdots\\ a_n\end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec{v_2} = \begin{bmatrix}\ b_1\\ \vdots\\ b_n\end{bmatrix}$, then

$$\vec{v_1}^T\vec{v_2} = [a_1\ \dots\ a_n]\begin{bmatrix}\ b_1\\ \vdots\\ b_n\end{bmatrix} = a_1b_1 + \dots + a_nb_n = \vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{v_2}.$$